# How to use multiple sliders with the same id on the same page?

Tags: javascript

I have more sliders on the same page, all of them have the same id. The problem is as soo as my image list ends on one slider, it jumps to the next slider. This is what I have now : https://jsfiddle.net/fvcpbrym/5/

```
function Slider() {
    this.buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.slider button');
    this.items = document.querySelectorAll('.slider .item');
    this.activeItem = 0;
    this.isSliding = false;

    this.addListeners = function () {
        this.buttons.forEach(el => el.addEventListener("click", this.slide))
    }

    this.slide = event => {
        if (!this.isSliding) {
            this.isSliding = true;
            var currentItem = this.activeItem;

            if(event.target === this.buttons[1]) {
                this.activeItem === this.items.length - 1 ? this.activeItem = 0 : this.activeItem++;
                //active slide out left
                this.items[currentItem].classList.add('active-left');
                //next slide in left
                this.items[this.activeItem].classList.add('item-next', 'item-left');
                //remove classes
                setTimeout(() => {
                    this.items[currentItem].classList.remove('active-left', 'active');
                    this.items[this.activeItem].classList.remove('item-next', 'item-left');
                    //set new active item
                    this.items[this.activeItem].classList.add('active');
                    this.isSliding = false;
                }, 1000)
            } else {
                this.activeItem === 0 ? this.activeItem = this.items.length - 1 : this.activeItem--;
                //active slide out right
                this.items[currentItem].classList.add('active-right');
                //prev slide in right
                this.items[this.activeItem].classList.add('item-prev', 'item-right');
                //remove classes
                setTimeout(() => {
                    this.items[currentItem].classList.remove('active-right', 'active');
                    this.items[this.activeItem].classList.remove('item-prev', 'item-right');
                    //set new active item
                    this.items[this.activeItem].classList.add('active');
                    this.isSliding = false;
                }, 1000)
            }
        }
    }
}

var slider = new Slider();
slider.addListeners();
```

Comment: Never use same `id`.

Comment: id values must be unique in a given HTML page

Comment: in my case I have multiple menus where I get these images from API, I don't know how many sliders I will have, that is why everywhere is the same id. Are you suggesting to inline that js with different ids?

Comment: The same id for more than one element is simply wrong. You can use `class` strings instead, or something else, but unique id values is just the way HTML works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the published code you do not have elements with the same ID.
I made a change to your JS code and I think it will work for you.

I add a unique CLASS to the wrap elements so that the function can call the HTML code according to the unique class

```js
var allWrap = document.getElementsByClassName('slider');

for (var i = 0; i < allWrap.length; i++) {
    allWrap[i].classList.add('mySlider_' + i);

    var slider = new Slider('.mySlider_' + i);
    slider.addListeners();
}


function Slider(newclass) {
    this.buttons = document.querySelectorAll(newclass + ' button');
    this.items = document.querySelectorAll(newclass + ' .item');
    this.activeItem = 0;
    this.isSliding = false;

    this.addListeners = function () {
        this.buttons.forEach(el => el.addEventListener("click", this.slide))
    }

    this.slide = event => {
        if (!this.isSliding) {
            this.isSliding = true;
            var currentItem = this.activeItem;

            if (event.target === this.buttons[1]) {
                this.activeItem === this.items.length - 1 ? this.activeItem = 0 : this.activeItem++;
                //active slide out left
                this.items[currentItem].classList.add('active-left');
                //next slide in left
                this.items[this.activeItem].classList.add('item-next', 'item-left');
                //remove classes
                setTimeout(() => {
                    this.items[currentItem].classList.remove('active-left', 'active');
                    this.items[this.activeItem].classList.remove('item-next', 'item-left');
                    //set new active item
                    this.items[this.activeItem].classList.add('active');
                    this.isSliding = false;
                }, 1000)
            } else {
                this.activeItem === 0 ? this.activeItem = this.items.length - 1 : this.activeItem--;
                //active slide out right
                this.items[currentItem].classList.add('active-right');
                //prev slide in right
                this.items[this.activeItem].classList.add('item-prev', 'item-right');
                //remove classes
                setTimeout(() => {
                    this.items[currentItem].classList.remove('active-right', 'active');
                    this.items[this.activeItem].classList.remove('item-prev', 'item-right');
                    //set new active item
                    this.items[this.activeItem].classList.add('active');
                    this.isSliding = false;
                }, 1000)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```css
.slider {
    display: flex;
    position: relative;

}
.next, .prev {
    border: none;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background: none;
    font-size: 30px;
    background-color: #eee;
}
.next:hover,
.prev:hover {
    background-color: #ddd;
}
.prev {
    order: 1;
}
.inner {
    position: relative;
    flex-grow: 1;
    order: 2;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.next {
    order: 3;
}
.item {
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
}
.image {
    width: 23%;
    margin: 0 1%;
    display: inline-block;
}
img {
    width: 100%;
}

.active {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
}
.item-next,
.item-prev {
    top: 0;
    display: block;
    z-index: 1;
}
.item-next {
    left: 100%;
}
.item-prev {
    left: -100%;
}
.item-left {
    animation: slideInLeft 1s forwards;
}

.item-right {
    animation: slideInRight 1s forwards;
}

.active-left {
    animation: slideOutLeft 1s forwards;
}
.active-right {
    animation: slideOutRight 1s forwards;
}


@keyframes slideInLeft {
    from {left:100%;}
    to {left:0;}
}

@keyframes slideInRight {
    from {left:-100%;}
    to {left:0;}
}

@keyframes slideOutLeft {
    from {left:0;}
    to {left:-100%;}
}

@keyframes slideOutRight {
    from {left:0;}
    to {left:100%;}
}
```

```html
<div class="slider">
    <div class="inner">
        <div class="item active">
            <div class="image">
                <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1494256997604-768d1f608cac?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=2001&q=80"
                    alt="kotek">
            </div>
            <div class="image">
                <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1494256997604-768d1f608cac?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=2001&q=80"
                    alt="kotek">
            </div>
            <div class="image">
                <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1494256997604-768d1f608cac?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=2001&q=80"
                    alt="kotek">
            </div>
            <div class="image">
                <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1494256997604-768d1f608cac?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=2001&q=80"
                    alt="kotek">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <div class="image">
                <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1494256997604-768d1f608cac?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=2001&q=80"
                    alt="kotek">
            </div>
            <div class="image">
                <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1494256997604-768d1f608cac?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=2001&q=80"
                    alt="kotek">
            </div>
            <div class="image">
                <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1494256997604-768d1f608cac?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=2001&q=80"
                    alt="kotek">
            </div>
            <div class="image">
                <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1494256997604-768d1f608cac?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=2001&q=80"
                    alt="kotek">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <button class="prev">&lt;</button>
    <button class="next">&gt;</button>
</div>



<div class="slider">
    <div class="inner">
        <div class="item active">
            <div class="image">
                <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1494256997604-768d1f608cac?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=2001&q=80"
                    alt="kotek">
            </div>
            <div class="image">
                <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1494256997604-768d1f608cac?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=2001&q=80"
                    alt="kotek">
            </div>
            <div class="image">
                <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1494256997604-768d1f608cac?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=2001&q=80"
                    alt="kotek">
            </div>
            <div class="image">
                <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1494256997604-768d1f608cac?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=2001&q=80"
                    alt="kotek">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <div class="image">
                <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1494256997604-768d1f608cac?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=2001&q=80"
                    alt="kotek">
            </div>
            <div class="image">
                <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1494256997604-768d1f608cac?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=2001&q=80"
                    alt="kotek">
            </div>
            <div class="image">
                <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1494256997604-768d1f608cac?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=2001&q=80"
                    alt="kotek">
            </div>
            <div class="image">
                <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1494256997604-768d1f608cac?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=2001&q=80"
                    alt="kotek">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <button class="prev">&lt;</button>
    <button class="next">&gt;</button>
</div>
```

Comment: this is exactly what I needed. Thank you!

Comment: I am glad that I was able to help! :) Thank you for the accepted answer and if you want you can give and a positive vote to my answer

Comment: sure. You deserve it. I was stuck with this for a while.